# Instead an element in a Laravel Colletion each 3 elements

Tags: laravel, collections

I have a collection with 4 Object :

```
Collection{#645 ▼
#items: array:4 [▼
0 => Team {#644 ▶}
1 => Team {#613 ▶}
2 => Team {#607 ▶}
3 => Team {#599 ▶}
   ]
}
```

I would like to insert a element each 3, begining by 0 index ( In this case, it would be in 0, and 3)

How should I do it???

The push method doesn't allow me to insert between to elements....

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) helper. I've tested this and it works perfectly:

```
$counter = 0;
$collection->map(function($i) use(&$counter) {
    if ($counter % 3 === 0) {
        $i->custom = 'Custom value';
    }
    $counter++;
    return $i;
});
```

Comment: this will not insert an object each 3 elements, this will insert a custom property in existing object each 3 elements.... am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're asked about inserting an element, I was sure you're talking about property.

Comment: I did it they clásic way. Will post it tomorrow